# Unable to resolve sh: 1: cannot create /tmp/vcsSemKey_ServiceId: Permission denied

Tags: command-line, permissions, sudo

I recently tried installing fingerprint driver on my device from [this link](https://balintbanyasz.wordpress.com/2015/03/27/get-validity-vfs-495-fingerprint-reader-working-in-ubuntu-14-04/#comment-58). Now, none of the sudo commands work and show up this error:

```
sh: 1: cannot create /tmp/vcsSemKey_ServiceId: Permission denied
sh: 1: cannot create /tmp/vcsSemKey_ServiceId: Permission denied
fp:error [dev_init] VFS module failed to wait for service
fp:error [fp_dev_open] device initialisation failed, driver=Validity
```

[image: Here are the images[1]]

[image: Here are the images[2]]

Please explain in the easiest way possible, I'm not a geek or anything.

Answer (score 0):

I got it fixed by deleting all the packages related to the fingerprint sensor using Synaptic Package Manager. The terminal had already  gotten too much buggy to fix the issue from there.